# Generate a raw preview of files which outputs formatting

Tags: php

Building a `Raw` view of text in my application, like pastebin does:

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=nfVT7b0Z

So, I wrote the script which just echos out the `$contents`, but newlines, spaces, and tabes are not being proceeded. Looking at the pastebin source above, you will notice they don't wrap the text in any HTML tags such as `<pre>`. How then are they getting the text to format?

Are they using some special header?

Answer (score 3):

The content you see is not HTML. It's text. You can use the following header to achieve the same result with output sent by php.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo "First Line\nSecond Line";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Curl was my friend here. I noticed in the response this header:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

So simply do:

```
    header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Before outputting any text.